# Use other references value from firebase realtime trigger functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Hi I started add some backend logic to my android app using firebase functions I want to use some value different then event data value

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('path')
     .onWrite(event => {
      const original = event.data.val();
      //I want to use value like this.
      const other_val= root.database.ref('path').val();
      console.log('email', "firms", original);
      const uppercase = original.toUpperCase();
      return event.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(uppercase);
    });
```

I want to use other_valwith event data but so far I just using event data ref but I can ascend or descend in database  event.data.ref using more parent or child. How can I solve it?

Edit:
I try and learn correct way to do this thanks to @davidtaubmann for his answer.

```
exports.makeUppercase = functions.database.ref('/nonVerifiedUsers/{email}')
     .onWrite(event => {

      var changed= "";
      // You can use ref parameter like this
      var param=event.params.email;
      admin.database().ref('/uppercase').once('value').then(function(snap){
      changed=snap.val();
          }).then(function(){
              /*if you want to use changed value wait until it return and return where 
              you want using admin.database.ref and use event parameter in reference like 
              this*/
              return admin.database.ref('/path/').child(param).set(changed);
              /*You can return regular event data but make sure you didn't write under 
              same reference server count this again as event and loop until reach 32 th child(maxiumum child nodes)*/
              return event.data.ref.parent.child('uppercase').set(changed);
          });
       //In addition you can return multiple times in one function:
        return event.data.ref.parent.child('dif').set(changed);

      
      });
```

Comment: I believe that if you need different access permissions as the user that generated the write, you need [adminRef](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot#adminRef), I have the same situation as you, but never thought of ascending and descending with parent, I'll try to solve it that way.

Comment: I've just found that inside the node-modules in the functions folder there's a [firebase-admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) module, if we assure it is activated in the functions package.json file and initialize it at the beginning of index.js, we might use it directly from the functions construction... I'll test both possibilities in the next hours.

Comment: As told in the comments on my answer... Try changing this `admin.database().ref('uppercase').on('value',function(snap){` for this `admin.database().ref('uppercase').once('value').then(function(snap){`

Comment: how do I assign a global variable value from the snapshot, the way Ogulcan has assigned var changed is not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### use firebase-admin node_module

Following my comments above, I did tested the options and as thought, if you initialize the Firebase-admin from node_modules (be sure it is also included in packages.json) you can retrieve any data from the database.

For your code I believe you only have to add this 2 lines at the beginning of the `index.js` file (with all the other initializations):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

then you can later use the `admin` as you would commonly use `firebase`, like this:

```
admin.database().ref('users/xxxx').once('value').then(function(snapshot){....
```

It just works perfectly for me!

Comment: I tried your suggestion but in the onWrite 'admin.database().ref('uppercase').on('value',function(snap){
         console.log(snap.val())
      }); ' It give me nothing

Comment: I believe you should use ONCE not ON, it's very different, and functions might have ON disabled, since it is not a client. TIP: you can send to console.log whatever you need and view the result in the Firebase Console / Functions / Registries tab

Comment: Can you give more specific example Like can i assign value in variable at then method?

Comment: @ogulcan I only used reading statements, so I'm not sure, but I believe the admin module should have writing permits for the entire Database too.

Comment: I tried like   admin.database().ref('/users').once('value').then(function(snap){
      original=snap.val();
}); I log the original after that. Log is Promise { <pending> }